# Playwright - wait for td value to change

Tags: typescript, playwright

I have a page where the api is reloading every few seconds. The response is rendered to a table. I would like to assert the first row and third column and check if the value is "Completed".
Can the waitForSelector work in this case?

Comment: How about `page.getByText("Completed", {exact: true})`? You can filter by the role or selector if that's not specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try without explicitly waiting. if it doesn't does the job, use `waitForSelector` which keeps on retrying until the element with matching text is found or it times out.

Without explicit wait:

```js
await expect(page.locator('table tr:first-child td:nth-child(3)')).toHaveText('Completed');
```

With explicit wait:

```js
await expect(page.waitForSelector('table tr:first-child td:nth-child(3)')).toHaveText('Completed');
```